# How to find the version of xkb on my machine

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb

A new keyboard layout of interest was recently checked into xkb. Since current version of xkb is at [2.19](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/XKeyboardConfig/), I think my layout will be shipped with 2.20.

How do I find out what version of xkb is currently installed on my machine ? I know I am using `X.Org version: 1.15.1` (from `xdpyinfo`). Does xkb come bundled with X11 ? or do the distros include it themselves ? Where is the information about the version of xkb shipped with a given release of a distro.

```
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint 
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.3 
DISTRIB_CODENAME=rosa
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa" 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr" 
ID=ubuntu 
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS" 
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"

Linux venkat-U46E 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Which distribution are you using - for which one do you need to know?

Comment: I have added distribution & version information to the question. Please take a look.

Comment: The layouts are in conf files. See `apt-cache policy xkb-data`

Comment: On Redhat/Fedora, Archlinux it's called `xkeyboard-config`, almost identical to the upstream name.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas TY I see it outputs the following. So, does this mean `xkb version` is `2.10.1` ? I ask to make sure the name is `xkb-data` refers to xkb app.

`xkb-data:
  Installed: 2.10.1-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.10.1-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.10.1-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://mirror.cs.umn.edu/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: Debian-based distributions (including Ubuntu and Mint) use `xkeyboard-config` as a [source package](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/xkeyboard-config) but the binary package is [`xkb-data`](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/xkb-data).  v2.20 isn't available yet in Debian unstable; you could try grabbing the v2.20 source and applying the Debian packaging files from v2.19, but that might not work without some massaging.